# filtering and displaying searchbar results from firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, search, firebase-realtime-database, uisearchbar

I am just starting to learn swift and firebase. I want to add a search bar that will allow users to search through my firebase database. This is what I want to get
[image: Desired UI]
I have added the searchbar, what I'm having problem with is the display of search result. 
I created a container view that include Name, subdescription and logo like the image above and then set them up with this function

```
    func searchResultContainer(){
    searchResultView.addSubview(businesslogoView)
    searchResultView.addSubview(businessNameLabel)
    searchResultView.addSubview(businessSectorLabel)

    //need x. y, width, height constraints for searchResult
    searchResultView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    searchResultView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
    searchResultView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 220).isActive = true
}
```

I then append the searchResult view to var bussinesarray. and then insert it into the tableview. Please see my code below

```
var businessArray = [NSDictionary]()
var filterBusiness = [NSDictionary]()

var ref : FIRDatabaseReference!

let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.businessArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
    ref.child("Businesses").queryOrdered(byChild: "Basic-Info/business").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

    view.addSubview(searchResultView)
    searchResultContainer()

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // if searchbar is not empty "", then return filtered businesses if the user is not typing anything return all businesses.
    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text !=
        ""{
        return filterBusiness.count
    }
    return self.businessArray.count

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    let business : NSDictionary?
    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text !=
        ""{
        business = filterBusiness[indexPath.row]
    }
    else
    {
        business = self.businessArray[indexPath.row]
    }
    cell.textLabel?.text = business?["Business"] as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = business?["handle"] as? String

    return cell

}

func filterContent (searchText:String) {
    self.filterBusiness = self.businessArray.filter{ Businesses in
        let businessName = Businesses["Business"] as? String
        return(businessName?.contains(searchText.lowercased()))!
    }
    tableView.reloadData()

}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    // update the search results
    filterContent(searchText: self.searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }
```

I am not getting the search result from firebase DB, how do I correctly implement the search result from firebase DB? I am building everything programmatically, please a sample code with be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The filterContent is called? I think you are not sending the request to fireBase DB, you are only filtering the array that you have.

Comment: how would you send the request to firebase DB

Comment: take a look at the doc, [here's the link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query)
Look at startAt(), endAt(), and equalTo()

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial was a great help for me in figuring out a similar implementation, see the code near the bottom of the tutorial.

http://shrikar.com/swift-ios-tutorial-uisearchbar-and-uisearchbardelegate/

Code adjustments beyond this tutorial included the below code. I still have some clean up that could be done around the if/else section however the two critical concepts for me was using the model and getting the target correct with: **let temp: NSString = text.EntityName! as NSString**

### Model file:

```
class Dealer: NSObject{

    var DealerNumber: String?
    var EntityName: String?
    //matchup all other firebase data fields
}
```

### ViewController Adjustments

```
var dealerList = [Dealer]()
var filterDealers = [Dealer]()

---      

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filterDealers = dealerList.filter({ (text) -> Bool in

        let temp: NSString = text.EntityName! as NSString
        let range = temp.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
        return range.location != NSNotFound

    })

    if(filterDealers.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    refreshTable()
}

----

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

    cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

    if(searchActive){
        cell?.textLabel?.text = filterDealers[indexPath.row].EntityName
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = filterDealers[indexPath.row].DealerNumber

    } else {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = dealerList[indexPath.row].EntityName
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = dealerList[indexPath.row].DealerNumber
    }

    return cell!;
}
```